# Why does my function(on binary tree) print an unexpected result?

Tags: c++, function, binary-tree

I wanna a make function , which takes as parametrs a binary tree ,t,  and two integers a,b and prints how many integers are between a and b...

As example here is a binary tree ,with three nodes and data :
10,15,20.
I call this function for example  : between(t ,10 ,20) and as result i expect the number 1 , but this does not happen..
My function is :

```
   `
int between (tree t, int a, int b) {
    if (t== NULL) 
       return 0;
    if ((t->data >a ) && ( t->data <b))
       return 1 + between(t->left,a,b) + between(t->right,a,b);
}
```

Can anyone explain me ?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: There may exist numbers in the subtrees that fall within the range, even if the root does not fall within the range. E.g. in your example you could have an unbalanced tree, with 10 at the root, 15 on its right, and 20 on the right of that. In this case, your code won't even look down the tree.

Comment: Besides, your program may exhibit undefined behavior by way of reaching the end of a `void` function without encountering a `return` statement. You don't return anything when neither of the two conditions holds.

Comment: Is your binary tree ordered (sorted) in any way? I don't see it mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the number is not between a and b, you have not defined a return value, which is an error other than your program doesnt do what it is required, but the function doesnt return an `int` value.

Secondly, you should go on, when the value is not on your range.
Your function should look like this:

```
int between (tree t, int a, int b) {
    if (t== NULL) 
       return 0;
    if ((t->data >a ) && ( t->data <b))
       return 1 + between(t->left,a,b) + between(t->right,a,b);
    else return between(t->left,a,b) + between(t->right,a,b);

}
```

Better yet, **IF** the values on the left are lower than values on the right (search tree) you can make an improvement.

```
int between (tree t, int a, int b) {
    if (t== NULL) 
       return 0;
    if ((t->data >a ) && ( t->data <b))
       return 1 + between(t->left,a,b) + between(t->right,a,b);
    else if(t->data<a) 
         return between(t->right,a,b);
    else if(t->data>b)
         return between(t->left,a,b);
}
```